# Can anyone identify this weed seen near Toronto?

Tags: identification, weeds

It was found in the Toronto area in Ontario, Canada. Here's a picture:

[image: Weed Picture]

Comment: I was amused that someone was asking about "weed" from GTA V and thought it might be more appropriate in http://gaming.stackexchange.com/, but then I realized it was a legitimate question. :)

Answer (score 8):

Looks like an immature dandelion to me.

Comment: That's what it is. Unlikely to flower and be positively identified this late in the year.

Comment: In our family, at that tender stage, known as salad greens.

Answer (score 2):

This is most definitely a dandelion. It has just not begun to sprout a blossom yet. I have a lot of these in my yard.